# r - defining path for read_excel with paste0

Tags: r, path

I'm working on an R script that is supposed to open an excel file from a folder in the current user computer using `read_excel` from `readxl` library.

The path will have a personal folder (C:/Users/**Username**....).

I'm trying to accomplish that as follows:

```
string <- getwd()
name <- strsplit(strsplit(x = string, split = "C:/Users/")[[1]][2], split = "/")[[1]][1]
path_crivo <- paste0("C:/Users/", name, "/some_folders/excel_file.xlsx")
```

So `path_crivo` stores the string: `C:/Users/João Anselmo/some_folders/excel_file.xlsx"`

When I run the read_excel function with this path I get the error:

```
read_excel(path_crivo)

"Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'C:/Users/JoÃ£o Anselmo/some_folders/excel_file.xlsx' cannot be opened."
```

If I set path_crivo directly as follows:

`path_crivo <- "C:/Users/João Anselmo/some_folders/excel_file.xlsx"`

It works perfectly. 
Anyone have faced a similar problem?
I can't rename the folders, nor set `path_crivo` directly, it is supposed to be a personal path. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: what does `Encoding(name)` give you?

Comment: `path_crivo` is of class `character`

Comment: Encoding(name) gives me "UTF-8"

Comment: Why split anything? If you are setting your work directory with `setwd()`, you can reference Excel file relatively: `read_excel('some_folders/excel_file.xlsx')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Encoding(path_crivo)<-"latin1"
```

(or, possibly, change the encoding of `string` before you create path_crivo)

Comment: if I set `Encoding(path_crivo)<-"latin1"` or even `Encoding(string)<-"latin1"`, read_excel returns `path does not exist: ‘C:/Users/JoÃ£o Anselmo/`

Comment: In other functions as `load` or `read.csv` I have no problem with the path name, only `read_excel` returns this message

Comment: If it's any consolation, this appears to be a known bug... https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/370